# Collation type in column decleration

Tags: slick, slick-2.0

My following column declaration ends up with a varchar(254) column in latin1_* (by default) collation in **MySQL** db.

```
def note = column[String]("NOTE")
```

I want to explicitly provide the collation. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, instead i ended up using postgresql.